# Which characters are considered unsafe and should be blocked from a text input field?

Tags: javascript, security

Which characters are considered unsafe to allow for users to type in a text input field, to prevent hackers etc to perform SQL injections etc? Which characters should be blocked from the input?

---

For the record, I'm currently blocking the input with AngularJS using the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern-restrict='^[^<>#*"]+$'>
```

And here's the beautiful directive I found:

```
/*  RESTRICT CERTAIN CHARACTERS IN INPUT FIELDS
    <input type="text" ng-pattern-restrict="^[A-Za-z0-9]*$">

    Alpha numeric chars only    ^[A-Za-z0-9]*$
    Date format YYYY-MM-DD      ^\d{0,4}(-\d{0,2}(-\d{0,2})?)?$
*/

/*jslint browser: true, plusplus: true, indent: 2 */

// This will be removed by uglify, along with the DEBUG code
if (typeof DEBUG === 'undefined') {
  DEBUG = true;
}

// Logic and fallbacks based on the following SO answers:
// - Getting caret position cross browser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9370239/147507
// - Selection API on non input-text fields: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24247942/147507
// - Set cursor position on input text: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5755826/147507
angular.module('ngPatternRestrict', [])
  .directive('ngPatternRestrict', ['$log', function ($log) {
    'use strict';

    function showDebugInfo() {
      $log.debug("[ngPatternRestrict] " + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' '));
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: "?ngModel",
      compile: function uiPatternRestrictCompile() {
        DEBUG && showDebugInfo("Loaded");

        return function ngPatternRestrictLinking(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {
          var regex, // validation regex object
            oldValue, // keeping track of the previous value of the element
            caretPosition, // keeping track of where the caret is at to avoid jumpiness
            // housekeeping
            initialized = false, // have we initialized our directive yet?
            eventsBound = false, // have we bound our events yet?
            // functions
            getCaretPosition, // function to get the caret position, set in detectGetCaretPositionMethods
            setCaretPosition; // function to set the caret position, set in detectSetCaretPositionMethods

          //-------------------------------------------------------------------
          // caret position
          function getCaretPositionWithInputSelectionStart() {
            return iElement[0].selectionStart; // we need to go under jqlite
          }

          function getCaretPositionWithDocumentSelection() {
            // create a selection range from where we are to the beggining
            // and measure how much we moved
            var range = document.selection.createRange();
            range.moveStart('character', -iElement.val().length);
            return range.text.length;
          }

          function getCaretPositionWithWindowSelection() {
            var s = window.getSelection(),
              originalSelectionLength = String(s).length,
              selectionLength,
              didReachZero = false,
              detectedCaretPosition,
              restorePositionCounter;

            do {
              selectionLength = String(s).length;
              s.modify('extend', 'backward', 'character');
              // we're undoing a selection, and starting a new one towards the beggining of the string
              if (String(s).length === 0) {
                didReachZero = true;
              }
            } while (selectionLength !== String(s).length);

            detectedCaretPosition = didReachZero ? selectionLength : selectionLength - originalSelectionLength;
            s.collapseToStart();

            restorePositionCounter = detectedCaretPosition;
            while (restorePositionCounter-- > 0) {
              s.modify('move', 'forward', 'character');
            }
            while (originalSelectionLength-- > 0) {
              s.modify('extend', 'forward', 'character');
            }

            return detectedCaretPosition;
          }

          function setCaretPositionWithSetSelectionRange(position) {
            iElement[0].setSelectionRange(position, position);
          }

          function setCaretPositionWithCreateTextRange(position) {
            var textRange = iElement[0].createTextRange();
            textRange.collapse(true);
            textRange.moveEnd('character', position);
            textRange.moveStart('character', position);
            textRange.select();
          }

          function setCaretPositionWithWindowSelection(position) {
            var s = window.getSelection(),
              selectionLength;

            do {
              selectionLength = String(s).length;
              s.modify('extend', 'backward', 'line');
            } while (selectionLength !== String(s).length);
            s.collapseToStart();

            while (position--) {
              s.modify('move', 'forward', 'character');
            }
          }

          // HACK: Opera 12 won't give us a wrong validity status although the input is invalid
          // we can select the whole text and check the selection size
          // Congratulations to IE 11 for doing the same but not returning the selection.
          function getValueLengthThroughSelection(input) {
            // only do this on opera, since it'll mess up the caret position
            // and break Firefox functionality
            if (!/Opera/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
              return 0;
            }

            input.focus();
            document.execCommand("selectAll");
            var focusNode = window.getSelection().focusNode;
            return (focusNode || {}).selectionStart || 0;
          }

          //-------------------------------------------------------------------
          // event handlers
          function revertToPreviousValue() {
            if (ngModelController) {
              scope.$apply(function () {
                ngModelController.$setViewValue(oldValue);
              });
            }
            iElement.val(oldValue);

            if (!angular.isUndefined(caretPosition)) {
              setCaretPosition(caretPosition);
            }
          }

          function updateCurrentValue(newValue) {
            oldValue = newValue;
            caretPosition = getCaretPosition();
          }

          function genericEventHandler(evt) {
            DEBUG && showDebugInfo("Reacting to event:", evt.type);

            //HACK Chrome returns an empty string as value if user inputs a non-numeric string into a number type input
            // and this may happen with other non-text inputs soon enough. As such, if getting the string only gives us an
            // empty string, we don't have the chance of validating it against a regex. All we can do is assume it's wrong,
            // since the browser is rejecting it either way.
            var newValue = iElement.val(),
              inputValidity = iElement.prop("validity");
            if (newValue === "" && iElement.attr("type") !== "text" && inputValidity && inputValidity.badInput) {
              DEBUG && showDebugInfo("Value cannot be verified. Should be invalid. Reverting back to:", oldValue);
              evt.preventDefault();
              revertToPreviousValue();
            } else if (newValue === "" && getValueLengthThroughSelection(iElement[0]) !== 0) {
              DEBUG && showDebugInfo("Invalid input. Reverting back to:", oldValue);
              evt.preventDefault();
              revertToPreviousValue();
            } else if (regex.test(newValue)) {
              DEBUG && showDebugInfo("New value passed validation against", regex, newValue);
              updateCurrentValue(newValue);
            } else {
              DEBUG && showDebugInfo("New value did NOT pass validation against", regex, newValue, "Reverting back to:", oldValue);
              evt.preventDefault();
              revertToPreviousValue();
            }
          }

          //-------------------------------------------------------------------
          // setup based on attributes
          function tryParseRegex(regexString) {
            try {
              regex = new RegExp(regexString);
            } catch (e) {
              throw "Invalid RegEx string parsed for ngPatternRestrict: " + regexString;
            }
          }

          //-------------------------------------------------------------------
          // setup events
          function bindListeners() {
            if (eventsBound) {
              return;
            }

            iElement.bind('input keyup click', genericEventHandler);

            DEBUG && showDebugInfo("Bound events: input, keyup, click");
          }

          function unbindListeners() {
            if (!eventsBound) {
              return;
            }

            iElement.unbind('input', genericEventHandler);
            //input: HTML5 spec, changes in content

            iElement.unbind('keyup', genericEventHandler);
            //keyup: DOM L3 spec, key released (possibly changing content)

            iElement.unbind('click', genericEventHandler);
            //click: DOM L3 spec, mouse clicked and released (possibly changing content)

            DEBUG && showDebugInfo("Unbound events: input, keyup, click");

            eventsBound = false;
          }

          //-------------------------------------------------------------------
          // initialization
          function readPattern() {
            var entryRegex = !!iAttrs.ngPatternRestrict ? iAttrs.ngPatternRestrict : iAttrs.pattern;
            DEBUG && showDebugInfo("RegEx to use:", entryRegex);
            tryParseRegex(entryRegex);
          }

          function notThrows(testFn, shouldReturnTruthy) {
            try {
                return testFn() || !shouldReturnTruthy;
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
          }

          function detectGetCaretPositionMethods() {
            var input = iElement[0];

            // Chrome will throw on input.selectionStart of input type=number
            // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21959157/147507
            if (notThrows(function () { return input.selectionStart; })) {
              getCaretPosition = getCaretPositionWithInputSelectionStart;
            } else {
              // IE 9- will use document.selection
              // TODO support IE 11+ with document.getSelection()
              if (notThrows(function () { return document.selection; }, true)) {
                getCaretPosition = getCaretPositionWithDocumentSelection;
              } else {
                getCaretPosition = getCaretPositionWithWindowSelection;
              }
            }
          }

          function detectSetCaretPositionMethods() {
            var input = iElement[0];
            if (typeof input.setSelectionRange === 'function') {
              setCaretPosition = setCaretPositionWithSetSelectionRange;
            } else if (typeof input.createTextRange === 'function') {
              setCaretPosition = setCaretPositionWithCreateTextRange;
            } else {
              setCaretPosition = setCaretPositionWithWindowSelection;
            }
          }

          function initialize() {
            if (initialized) {
              return;
            }
            DEBUG && showDebugInfo("Initializing");

            readPattern();

            oldValue = iElement.val();
            if (!oldValue) {
              oldValue = "";
            }
            DEBUG && showDebugInfo("Original value:", oldValue);

            bindListeners();

            detectGetCaretPositionMethods();
            detectSetCaretPositionMethods();

            initialized = true;
          }

          function uninitialize() {
            DEBUG && showDebugInfo("Uninitializing");
            unbindListeners();
          }

          iAttrs.$observe("ngPatternRestrict", readPattern);
          iAttrs.$observe("pattern", readPattern);

          scope.$on("$destroy", uninitialize);

          initialize();
        };
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Please note that it's also necessary to load this directive in the beginning:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngPatternRestrict']);
```

Comment: You prevent SQL injection from the backend, not the front-end. It's trivial to bypass client validation and send anything you want to the server.

Comment: Ditto what @JustinLessard said. You need to perfom the check on the server-side. You can optionally choose to do it on the front end for UX, but you must always do it on the back end.

Comment: Thanks Justin for your comment. I'll make sure I check it on the back-end as well. Still though, I wouldn't want users to be able to be able to type unsafe characters, so the question remains; which are the unsafe characters?

Comment: Exactly: front end defences do not help.  Learn about intercepting proxies.  Also, you don't stop sql injection by sanitisation: instead, the answer is prepared statements.  It's all backend stuff.  There is no magic that says that if you block certain characters, then you stop all possible attacks.  It just is not that simple.

Comment: This Martin Fowler article will explain why sanitisation, blacklisting characters, and front end protections are the wrong answer to your security problem: https://martinfowler.com/articles/web-security-basics.html

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you should solve this on the back-end by using prepared statements. It's the only way as the client can be edited relatively easily.
In Java, for example, you can use this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO student VALUES(?)");
stmt.setString(1, userInput);
stmt.execute();
```

This way the input is placed into the query as plain text, so SQL injection will not be an issue and Little Bobby Tables can go to your school.

Comment: While you're right, I don't feel like you are answering OP's question.

Comment: Yes and no. I didn't explicitly answer OP's question as I think it doesn't make too much sense to do elaborate filtering on the front end if it's going to be converted to plain text later on at the back end anyways.  
I think they should use a regex that allows only the characters they'd like to see in their DB, not disallow the ones that are "unsafe".